# C++ function calls, why is destructor used?

Tags: c++, function, destructor

I am trying to understand better function calls in C++. I have the following code:

```
class A{ 
  public:
    A() { cout << "hello\n"; }
    A(const A& obj) { cout << "world\n"; }
    ~A() { cout << "bye\n"; }

  virtual void print() { cout << "a\n"; }
};

A foo(A aobj)
{
    aobj.print();
    return aobj;
}

int main(){
  A a,b,c;
  foo(a);
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
hello //from calling A's default constructor

hello

hello

world //because we pass 'a' by value in funtion foo so the copy constructor is used


a

world //because foo returns by value so the copy constructor is used again

bye //?

bye //?
```

Could someone explain why the destructor is called twice at the end? Is it because of the two copy constructors calls?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: 2 times or 5 times, that's the question?

Comment: Why 5? "bye" is printed only 2 times in output.

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://ideone.com/9nG6DS). I get 5 `bye`.

Comment: There should be 5, 5 objects constructed, 5 objects deleted.

Comment: That's weird. I get only 2, but i suppose the 3 extra are justified because the objects a,b,c go out of scope so destructor is called

Comment: so the two "bye" are caused from the call of copy constructor? (regardless the other 3 which i currently dont see for some reason)

Comment: Check out the **rule of zero**, **rule of 3** and **rule of 5**.

Comment: If you see just two then the program you shared is not reproducible. Pls share with us a [minimal, complete and reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code.

Comment: I'm willing to bet this isn't your real code. You probably had something like `getchar()` or `system("pause")` at the end of main which is why you only got partial output.

Comment: I do have system("pause") because otherwise i wouldn't be able to see the output. I use visual studio. Does that affect the output? (I haven't work with C++ before or VS and I didnt consider system("pause") as something worth mentioning.)

Comment: Yes, of course it does. Some things happen at the end of `main`. Please only post the actual code you ran.

Comment: thank you i will keep that in mind

Answer (score 2):

"bye" is printed 5 times because `~A()` is also called 5 times. For objects `a`, `b`, `c` the destructor is called ones. Then as you pass `a` by value, a copy is created in `foo` which is then destroyed. Finally the return type of foo is an instance of `A` which is destroyed when execution moves to the next line. Thus in total, `~A()` will be called 5 times.

The destructor is called at the end of the lifetime of the object to release the memory which was used by the object.

Comment: Okay! Thank you for clarifying this!

Answer (score 1):

There are 5 objects created, so there will be 5 "bye"s outputted.

However, only 2 of the objects go out of scope and get destructed *before* your call to `system("pause")` (the 2 objects created by `foo()`). The other 3 objects go out of scope and get destructed *after* the call to `system("pause")`. So, you might not have a chance to see those 3 "bye"s if the console window closes when the app exits.

You can force those 3 objects to go out of scope sooner by introducing another shorter-lived scope for them to live in, either like this:

```
int main(){
    {
    A a,b,c;
    foo(a);
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Or like this:

```
void doIt(){
    A a,b,c;
    foo(a);
}

int main(){
    doIt();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Now all 5 objects will go out of scope and get destructed *before* the call to `system("pause")`.